# why multiple selection not working in r while single is working

Tags: r, shiny

I don't know what I am doing wrong here, I have tried multiple=TRUE and tried couple of other input method like multiselect and shiny widget drop down select but none of them seems to be working fine. It is working for single selection but when it comes to multiple selection or (select all) option in shiny widget, nothing is working. I have worked around this issue but that's not what I want and looking for a proper solution for this. It would be great if anyone could tell me what I am missing here and what could be done to get ride of this issue. All I need is to enable the multiple selection, that's all. I have given my work around code all the way down just for reference.
Please guide me through this issue. Any help and even a suggestion would be great.

Thanks from Sid

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)
library(lubridate)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinycustomloader)
library(htmltools)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinyWidgets)
re<-tibble::tribble(
      ~Order.ID, ~Order_Date, ~CustomerName,             ~State,     ~City, ~sales,
      "B-26180",  "4/5/2017", "Bhaggyasree",   "Andhra Pradesh", "Udaipur",   880L,
      "B-26248",  "4/6/2017",       "Mohit",            "Bihar", "Udaipur",   121L,
      "B-26262",  "4/7/2017",    "Vaibhavi", "Himachal Pradesh", "Udaipur",    24L,
      "B-26280",  "4/8/2017",      "Akshay", "Himachal Pradesh", "Udaipur",   145L,
      "B-26162",  "4/8/2017",      "Mitali",        "Karnataka", "Udaipur",   133L,
      "B-26254",  "4/9/2017",     "Noshiba",        "Karnataka", "Udaipur",   312L,
      "B-26156",  "4/9/2017",   "Chayanika",   "Madhya Pradesh", "Udaipur",  1103L)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Plotly - dateRangeInput"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
    inputId = "state",
    label = "state",
    multiple = TRUE,
    selected = re$State[1],
    choices = c(unique(re$State)))),
    mainPanel(
      fluidPage(withLoader(plotlyOutput("p1"),type = "html",loader = "loader2")))))

server<-function(input,output,session){
State <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "State"), {
    State(event_data("plotly_click", source = "State")$x)
  })
output$p1 <- renderPlotly({
  re %>% 
  count(input$state, wt = sales) %>%
  plot_ly(x = input$state, y = ~n, source = "State") %>%
  layout(title = "State")
})
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

below given is working but that is also not proper but I worked around it so what is the matter with the code given above. How to enable the multiple selection in previously given code.

```
if (interactive()) {

library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")
re<-tibble::tribble(
      ~Order.ID, ~Order_Date, ~CustomerName,             ~State,     ~City, ~sales,
      "B-26180",  "4/5/2017", "Bhaggyasree",   "Andhra Pradesh", "Udaipur",   880L,
      "B-26248",  "4/6/2017",       "Mohit",            "Bihar", "Udaipur",   121L,
      "B-26262",  "4/7/2017",    "Vaibhavi", "Himachal Pradesh", "Udaipur",    24L,
      "B-26162",  "4/8/2017",      "Mitali",        "Karnataka", "Udaipur",   133L,
      "B-26254",  "4/9/2017",     "Noshiba",        "rajasthan", "Udaipur",   312L,
      "B-26156",  "4/9/2017",   "Chayanika",   "Madhya Pradesh", "Udaipur",  1103L)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId = "id", label = "state :",
    choices = c(unique(re$State)),multiple = TRUE,
    selected = NULL, width = "350px"
  ),
  fluidPage(withLoader(plotlyOutput("res"),type = "html",loader = "loader2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res <- renderPlotly({
    re_filter <- filter(re,
                         State %in% input$id)
   plot_ly(data = re_filter,x = input$id, y = input$sales,type="bar")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is around here

```
output$p1 <- renderPlotly({
  re %>% 
  count(input$state, wt = sales) %>%
  plot_ly(x = input$state, y = ~n, source = "State") %>%
  layout(title = "State")
```

i tried to combined both of your code and got this.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)
library(lubridate)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinycustomloader)
library(htmltools)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinyWidgets)
re<-tibble::tribble(
  ~Order.ID, ~Order_Date, ~CustomerName,             ~State,     ~City, ~sales,
  "B-26180",  "4/5/2017", "Bhaggyasree",   "Andhra Pradesh", "Udaipur",   880L,
  "B-26248",  "4/6/2017",       "Mohit",            "Bihar", "Udaipur",   121L,
  "B-26262",  "4/7/2017",    "Vaibhavi", "Himachal Pradesh", "Udaipur",    24L,
  "B-26280",  "4/8/2017",      "Akshay", "Himachal Pradesh", "Udaipur",   145L,
  "B-26162",  "4/8/2017",      "Mitali",        "Karnataka", "Udaipur",   133L,
  "B-26254",  "4/9/2017",     "Noshiba",        "Karnataka", "Udaipur",   312L,
  "B-26156",  "4/9/2017",   "Chayanika",   "Madhya Pradesh", "Udaipur",  1103L)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Plotly - dateRangeInput"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "state",
        label = "state",
        multiple = TRUE,
        selected = re$State[1],
        choices = c(unique(re$State)))),
    mainPanel(
      fluidPage(withLoader(plotlyOutput("p1"),type = "html",loader = "loader2")))))

server<-function(input,output,session){
  State <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "State"), {
    State(event_data("plotly_click", source = "State")$x)
  })
  output$p1 <- renderPlotly({
    re_filter <- filter(re,
                        State %in% input$state)
    plot_ly(data = re_filter,x = re_filter$State, y = re_filter$sales,type="bar")
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

is this what you want?

Comment: yes, that's quite what I wanted but what about count function to aggregate the same names that occurred multiple times. When I try to put it where it was earlier and set the value with the filters that you did in the above given code, it throws error, could you please tell, where should I place that to get it done all. by the way thanks for help and quick response that you have given, thanks again

Comment: you can add `group_by` and summarise the value of it. change this `re_filter <- filter(re, State %in% input$state)` with `re_filter <- re %>% filter(State %in% input$state) %>% group_by(State) %>% summarise(total_sales = sum(sales))` 
also dont forget to change `re_filter$sales` in `plot_ly()` to `re_filter$total_sales`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and bearing with me for so long and I got it done with your help what I exactly wanted to do, thanks a lot again for your help